# Converting xml string to 'this' class using jackson

Tags: java, serialization, jackson-dataformat-xml

I am using Jackson to work with my XML data, based on [this Baeldung tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-xml-serialization-and-deserialization).

I have the following class to model *some* XML:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;

public class SimpleBean {

    private int x = 1;
    private int y = 2;

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public SimpleBean fromString(String xml) throws JsonProcessingException {
        XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
        return xmlMapper.readValue(xml, SimpleBean.class);
    }
}
```

I have the following test that passes:

```
@Test
void testFromString() throws Exception {
    SimpleBean bean = new SimpleBean();
    String xml = "<SimpleBean><x>11</x><y>22</y></SimpleBean>";
    SimpleBean beanParsed = bean.fromString(xml);
    Assertions.assertEquals(11, beanParsed.getX());
}
```

What I would like to do is something like this:

```
@Test
void testFromStringWanted() throws Exception {
    SimpleBean bean = new SimpleBean();
    String xml = "<SimpleBean><x>11</x><y>22</y></SimpleBean>";
    bean.fromString(xml);
    Assertions.assertEquals(11, bean.getX());  // FAILS
}
```

I would like to parse the string into the instance `bean` that I already have. I do not want to have to create a second `beanParsed`.

I tried to change my `fromString` method to:

```
public void fromString(String xml) throws JsonProcessingException {
    XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
    xmlMapper.readValue(xml, this.getClass());
}
```

but that did not work. No errors, it just did not produce the desired results.

Also tried this, but that does not even compile!

```
public void fromString(String xml) throws JsonProcessingException {
    XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
    this = xmlMapper.readValue(xml, SimpleBean.class);
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: How does it fail? `fromString` returns a Bean but you do not save/use it. `bean.getX()` returns a value that has not been set.

Comment: `fromString` is a [factory method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) and should be `static`.  Then you invoke it _without_ instantiating a `SimpleBean` first, because it returns the new `SimpleBean`.

Comment: For an example of a built-in factory method, look at the reason behind things like `Long.parseLong(String...)` and many others in the standard library.  This is what you want, not a hack to update the bean after creation.

Comment: @JimGarrison Thank you for the suggestion. In my case I will always have one instance of `SimpleBean`, I just wanted to be able to parse the `xml` string into the existing one. The answer that Nir gave, below, is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
public void fromString(String xml) throws JsonProcessingException {
    XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
    // Use readerForUpdating() to parse into the existing instance
    xmlMapper.readerForUpdating(this).readValue(xml);
}
```

Jackson provides a method called `readerForUpdating()` specifically for parsing data into an existing object.

This method creates a reader that updates an existing object instead of creating a new one.